# Ben Affleck says he does not use sarcasm because it is what?

Tags: the-accountant

In *[The Accountant](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2140479/?ref_=nv_sr_1)*, Ben Affleck's character says he does not use sarcasm because "it is *[word that sounds like irruficient]*".

I've not heard of that word before or as sarcasm being that. I have tried looking for "irruficient" under a number of different spellings and cannot find it.

What is he actually saying?

Comment: Why take "The Accountant" out of the post title? Is that policy? I get that it's in the tag, but it's much easier to see what's being asked if it's in the title.

Comment: @aryxus Yes, it is common practice as long as it hinders the reading flow. Your movie title should be in the tags and the question body already. If you find a way to integrate it more naturally into the question title, that's fine, but "The Accountant, ..." isn't really. For more information on the matter, see [this related meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1087/49).

Answer (score 11):

Dana (Anna Kendrick) asks "Is that sarcasm?"
Christian (Ben Affleck) responds "No, that's not sarcasm. I don't use sarcasm. It's irritation."

He means that what Dana took for sarcasm was actually him being irritated, and not sarcastic.

He doesn't use sarcasm because he doesn't 'get' it, due to his having Asperger's or another form of autism.